# Not a valid xpath expression issue in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a small issue that I am facing.
currently I use this code to find element:

```
BasePage.waitInvisabilityOfElementByXpath("//div[@class='ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion']");
```

All is working as expcted, However I want to try to use contains in this xpath, and not use the full path.
I start with exactly the same xpath using contains and get an error, while doing it with contains.

```
BasePage.waitInvisabilityOfElementByXpath("//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion'])");
```

I get this error

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion'])' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

what is wrong with my syntax regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `]` and `)` mixed up at the end.

`//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion'])`... see how you start with `[` but end with `)`.

Instead, try:

`//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion')]`

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are closing square bracket first instead of parentheses

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, you have your closing ] and ) backwards but I would like to suggest that you use a CSS selector. XPath has it's place but it's not necessary in this case. CSS selectors have several advantages over XPath:

1. There is better support for CSS selectors
2. The behavior in browsers is more consistent for CSS selectors
3. There is a minor performance advantage to using CSS selectors
4. When dealing with elements with a lot of classes (as in your case here), it's easier to use a CSS selector

Short version:
You can use the CSS selector below

```
div.ant-notification-notice.ant-notification-notice-closable.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-notificationMotion
```

Long version:
When you use an XPath like

```
//div[@class='ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion']
```

what this is doing is an exact string match for that large string that contains several classes. If another class gets added, the locator will fail. If the order of the classes is changed, the locator will fail... and so on. A CSS selector doesn't have these issues because it looks for the classes in any order and it doesn't matter if the element has additional classes.

XPath can be used for just about anything but as you can see above, there are drawbacks. Because of this, it is recommended by many/most speakers at Selenium conferences (seleniumconf and SauceCon, for examples) including many Selenium contributors that you use

1. ID
2. CSS selectors
3. XPath, only when necessary and it's only necessary when you are locating an element by contained text or doing DOM traversal

Comment: Selenium do seem to be a bit lukewarm about XPath given that they've failed to upgrade their product to support any version later than XPath 1.0 which is nearly 20 years old. Such a missed opportunity.

Comment: @MichaelKay My understanding is that it's not Selenium, it's the browser's implementation. Selenium only supplies it's own XPath implementation when the browser doesn't have a native one.

Comment: Thankyou, I wasn't aware of that. But it doesn't alter the fact, they've had an awful long time to improve their XPath support and have failed to do so.

Comment: @MichaelKay ...can't disagree with that.